# Murim manga about an arrogant main character who is killed by the protagonist and then travels back in time

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga

The main character lives his life arrogantly, only to meet the protagonist, who just came out of seclusion to be killed. He then travels back in time and makes different choices, living his life in a better way.

The sudden change was surprising to many, but as time passes, he apologizes to those he had wronged and pulls people who will become prodigies in the future to his side, while fighting with his siblings over becoming an heir and trying hard not to meet the protagonist.

**N.B:** he inherited heavenly demon inheritance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour? And did the MC have long hair or short hair?

Comment: Hmmm, if I remember correctly the mc have a long hair but it is tied at the back I think and it is full colour

Comment: What distinction do you intend by referring to different characters as the "main character" and "protagonist" here?

Comment: @Buzz I'm not familiar with Murim, but I *believe* this means the viewpoint character (the Main Character) encounters the Protagonist of an existing story. Specifically a story with a martial arts focus.

Comment: The Mc is a villian although he changed but because he came from heavenly demonic sect, the Murim alliance believe them to be evil.

Comment: And an unknown sect is using the name of the mc sect to commit crime